# CSS odd and even puts same color side by side

Tags: html, css

I do not want that the same color is side by side. At the moment: 1-2-1-1-2 but It must be: 1-2-1-2-1

HTML

```
<ul class="list list-unstyled">
  <li>The_hangover_part_1.avi<span class="pull-right">25Gb</span></li>
  <li>The_hangover_part_1_intro.avi<span class="pull-right">15Gb</span></li>
  <li>Covers<span class="pull-right">255Kb</span></li>
  <ul>
    <li>the_hangover_part_1_cover_1.jpg<span class="pull-right">123Kb</span></li>
    <li>the_hangover_part_1_cover_2.jpg<span class="pull-right">122Kb</span></li>
    <li>the_hangover_part_1_cover_2.jpg<span class="pull-right">122Kb</span></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.list li:nth-child(even) {
  background: transparent;
}
.list li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to correct your HTML. The `ul` element can't be nested directly in another `ul`, it must be inside one of the `li`s:

```
<ul class="list list-unstyled">
  <li>The_hangover_part_1.avi<span class="pull-right">25Gb</span></li>
  <li>The_hangover_part_1_intro.avi<span class="pull-right">15Gb</span></li>
  <li>Covers<span class="pull-right">255Kb</span>
    <ul>
      <li>the_hangover_part_1_cover_1.jpg<span class="pull-right">123Kb</span></li>
      <li>the_hangover_part_1_cover_2.jpg<span class="pull-right">122Kb</span></li>
      <li>the_hangover_part_1_cover_2.jpg<span class="pull-right">122Kb</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then, when you get the correct markup, you can redefine the order of colors for sub-items of the odd items of the main list:

```
.list li:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: transparent;
}
.list li:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `:nth-child` selector only looks at the position within its direct parent. To fix this, you can remove the `li` tags outside of their `ul` and indent them by giving them a class that contains the indentation style.

Comment: To the one who downvoted this answer, please comment to explain the reason.